# OSX Swift Writing a file as an admin (sudo)

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to build a MacOS app that handles changes to the hosts file. How can I write as admin? If needed I am willing to ask for the password.

```
let hostsURL =  NSURL.fileURL(withPath: "/etc/hosts")


do {
    var text2 = try String(contentsOf: hostsURL, encoding: .utf8)
    text2 += "\n127.0.0.1   facebook.com"
    NSLog(text2);
    try text2.write(to: hostsURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
}
catch {/* error handling here */
    NSLog("error");
}
```